# One New Relic account per IIS App Pool?

Tags: .net, iis, newrelic

Is it possible to have the New Relic .Net agent running on one host, to report to different accounts?

Looking at the documentation, is seems like the .NET agent is limited to 1 New Relic account:

```
<service licenseKey="key"
  ssl="false"
  sendEnvironmentInfo="true"
  syncStartup="false"
  sendDataOnExit="false"
  sendDataOnExitThreshold="60000">
```

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/dotnet-agent-configuration

Comment: Best to ask New Relic this directly. I've found them pretty helpful in the past.

Comment: Agree - very helpful indeed. Just wanted to make the information available for everyone :) I will update with answer upon hearing from New Relic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official answer from New Relic support is:

> "A instrumented New Relic agent can only report to one New Relic account."

But one option is to...

> "[...]upgrade your account to an enterprise account, which would allow you to create sub-accounts. Essentially, all sub-accounts are controlled by one master account, but that master account is inaccessible by any users on sub-accounts, unless they are explicitly added to it. This way, each user can have their own account explicitly for their application(s), and your account will still be above it."